# Recover unfinished mp4 file

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming, recording, file-corruption

I have a problem with a broken mp4 file. I was using livestreamer to get the YouTube live stream into VLC player and then I was saving it through Save/Convert functionality of VLC player as an H.264/mp4 file. The stream ended abruptly and my recording closed without properly finalizing the file and now I cannot read it.

I've googled around and most of the fixing software is done so that it can fix video if you have a proper video recorded with the same camera which I cannot have in that case (I tried saving some other stream of the same resolution but that reference didn't work with Video Repair Tool, a most recommended software for repairing videos).

I've found [this website](http://mp4repair.org).
It managed to show me previews of my video so I'm sure it can be fixed, however they charge 40 $ which is really expensive for where I live.

Does anybody have some suggestions to my situation? I'm sure the stream was recording properly, it just finished abruptly, so the data must be there, the problem seems to be with the headers or something along those lines.

Comment: Hello @pokrishka, don't pay for such a "tool", there are a lot of free of charge e.g. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: @duDE this software seems to recover lost files, in my case the file is there but it's damaged/not properly finalized.

Comment: Try this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mp4-video-repair-tool/ -> Tool to repair damaged or corrupt Mp4 video files that are unplayable or error out when opened.

Comment: @duDE as I mentioned in my question, I cannot get a working reference due to the nature of how my video was created so all that software that requires a working reference is not an option for me.

Comment: @duDE you should read the question fully before answering. Pokrishka: try using Handbrake to transcode the file, it may error at the end of the file, but should finalize its own output properly.

Comment: @Linef4ult Have many thanks, now we all (OP and myself) know what to do! :)

Comment: @Linef4ult unfortunately Handbrake cannot handle the file. It scans it an nothing happens, when I try to start the encoding it says I must first scan a source file.

Comment: FFMPEG mgiht do it then, but you may be out of luck at this point.

Comment: @Linef4ult thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately FFMPEG says "moov atom not found"